# How to check/detect an 'if' clause without curly braces?

Tags: c++

In a C/C++ code project, I would like to find all *if/else* sentences which are not using curly braces. Is there any compiler check or utility to find them?

The main problem is that I want to redefine some debug macros to avoid traces evaluation in some conditions (does any know any other solution?). And I need to find them to avoid the [“dangling-else problem”](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dangling_else), as pointed out in ["if" block without curly braces makes subsequent "else if" nested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11734604/if-block-without-curly-braces-makes-subsequent-else-if-nested)

Code pieces:

Before modification:

```
DEBUG GET_DEBUG_DST(DEBUG_LEVEL_DEBUG).nospace() << DEBUG_PREFIX << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__
```

Now we would use an `if` without braces inside:

```
DEBUG if (getDebugmode(DEBUG_LEVEL_DEBUG)) GET_DEBUG_DST(DEBUG_LEVEL_DEBUG).nospace() << DEBUG_PREFIX << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__
```

Example of problematic code:

```
if (my condition)
    DEBUG << "hi there";
else
    {some more code;}
```

Comment: In first place, it would be a better idea to replace this kind of debugging log with something reasonable and sane.

Comment: try to create a compilation error

Comment: @H2CO3 I know, but I didn't start it and I've to deal with it.

Comment: @Alon I've tried to think a way to raise a compilation error, but haven't found any yet. Any idea?

Comment: You could use a regular expression of the form `if\s*\(.*\)\s*^{` or similar but as others have commented you should fix the debugging code rather than the rest of the code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just invert the logic, and put the active part in the else
branch:

```
#define DEBUG if( !getDebugmode( DEBUG_LEVEL_DEBUG ) )              \
        ;                                                           \
    else                                                            \
        GET_DEBUG_DST( DEBUG_LEVEL_DEBUG ).nospace()                \
            << DEBUG_PREFIX << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__
```

Since there is a matching `else` for the `if`, it can't pick up
any additional `else`.

Comment: Good solution but since OP seems to assume that the `if` needs to be inside the `#define` it’s worth noting that this isn’t the case at all, and there are other solutions – one would be to have a proxy stream object in which the overloaded `operator<<` takes over the check for the debugging mode, and the macro would simply be `#define DEBUG get_stream_proxy() << DEBUG_PREFIX << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__` …

Comment: @KonradRudolph I thought that one, but I discarded it as it would not avoid evaluating all code after the operator<<, would it?

Comment: @kikeenrique I usually use the proxy solution myself.  Done correctly, the _expressions_ after the `<<` will be evaluated, but there will be no conversions unless tracing is active.  Typically, the expressions are fairly trivial, and the real cost is the conversion, but one never knows.

Answer (score 1):

> I would like to find in a c/c++ code project all if/else sentences which are not using curly braces. Is there any compiler check or utility to find them?

This sounds like the [x-y problem](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=542341). If you are trying to replace the DEBUG macro with a no-op that will not invalidate the syntax of the if, you can use:

```
#ifdef DEBUG_ENABLED
#define DEBUG GET_DEBUG_DST(DEBUG_LEVEL_DEBUG).nospace() << DEBUG_PREFIX // ...
#else
#define DEBUG do {;} while(false); /##/
#endif
```

In this case, the DEBUG will be a valid operation (doesn't invalidate the else due to nothing in the if block), and anything that's on the same line (the debug message data) will evaluate to:

```
if (my condition)
    do {;} while(false); // << "hi there";
else
    {some more code;}
```

This has the disadvantage of not allowing for multiline debug comments though:

```
if (my condition)
    DEBUG << "hi there"
        << "some more data on a different line"; // causes error if DEBUG is no-op
else
    {some more code;}
```

Comment: This fixes the problem in compilation time, which is solved in a similar way, but the purpose is to modify traces on runtime, thats why I need to use the if().

Comment: Unfortunately, like many preprocessing hacks, that won't work. Comments are removed *before* macro expansion, which works on preprocessor tokens rather than source characters. So after processing, you'll end up with two `/` tokens giving a syntax error.

Answer (score -1):

Bad idea.

Use:

#define debug(x) do { if (DEBUG_LEVEL) print_stuff(x); } while(0)

which avoids the issue.

Comment: The problem is the use of the macro, which currently is DEBUG << "something"; It would be easier that way, but changing the macro use is not possible.

Comment: You'll have to find all the broken code then. Not sure there is an easy way to do that...