# What does a 'for' loop without curly braces do?

Tags: c, for-loop

What does a *for* loop without any curly braces around it do?

So from what I know, that during an if-statement only the first line of the code is executed. So in a for loop how does it work?

I don't really understand the concept of a loop without the braces and with the braces. I guess an explanation with a piece of code would help. This is in C by the way. Here's a code I've been looking at as a reference.

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  int i;
  int count = 0;
  for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    count++;
    printf("The value of count is: %d\n", count);

  return 0;
}
```

In this case, I see that there is no curly braces, so I am assuming that it will just keep iterating the first statement until i < 5 and once i is not less than 5 it doesn't do anything, but when I tested the code I get that it also ends up printing the printf statement. I thought that a loop without curly braces executed only the first line of code? Or am I missing something here.

Comment: I know there is a duplicate of this, just can't find it...

Comment: What happens when you compile and run it? What happens if you then add an opening curly brace after the `for` and a closing one after the `printf`? It seems that about 30 seconds of effort would answer this for you, and it would be a lot quicker (and more educational) than posting here and waiting for an answer. There is absolutely nothing dangerous in that code that prevents you from making a little effort yourself.

Comment: @jpw I already tried a search before I asked the question but I couldn't find anything like what I was trying to ask

Comment: @KenWhite I actually did try this already and got an output which had the value of count at 5 and printed it, but I wanted to confirm if this always applied and how it worked

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When can I omit curly braces in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14901919/when-can-i-omit-curly-braces-in-c)

Comment: There is almost certainly a duplicate from 2008 (canonical).

Comment: Related (not duplicate, but probably not canonical either): [Dangling *else* problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11734604/)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Without curly braces, only the first statement following the loop definition is considered to belong to the loop body.

Notice that in your example, `printf` is only called once. Though its indentation matches the previous line, that's a red herring – C doesn't care. What it says to me is that whoever wrote the code probably forgot the braces, and *intended* the `printf` statement to be part of the loop body.

The only time I would leave out the curly braces is when writing a one-line `if` statement:

```
if (condition) statement;
do_something_else();
```

Here, there's no indentation to introduce ambiguity about whether the statement on the second line is actually supposed to belong to the body of the `if`. You would likely be more confident when reading this that it's working as intended.

Comment: So everything else would be considered outside of the body like @gmarintes said? And also does this apply for all loops and also if-statements?

Comment: Yes, it applies generally to loops and conditional statements. There are lots of discussions on Google; [here's](http://bytes.com/topic/c/answers/129149-braces-needed) a decent one.

Comment: Note that a one-line `do ... while` is awkward as it requires a semicolon after both the body statement and the condition.

Answer (score 3):

If the for-loop does not have braces, it will execute the next statement.
The syntax is essentially

```
for (<initialization>;<condition>;<increment>) <statement>;
```

The "statement" part can be anything. It could be a simple count++; or it could be an 'if'/'if-else' statement, it could even be another for-loop without the braces!

So in this case, the code is similar to:

```
for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    count++;
}
printf("The value of count is: %d\n", count);
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean by it will execute the statements until the next ';'? So is this similar to saying that if there is a condition in that first line of a loop it will keep iterating through it until it has completed and then finally go through the rest of the lines?

Comment: Yes. The syntax is essentially for (<initialization>;<condition>;<increment>) <statement>; The <statement> part can be anything. If could be a simple count++; or it could be an 'if'/'if-else' statement, it could even be another for-loop without the braces!

Comment: Alright thank you for the help, that cleared things up for me!

Comment: "Statements until the next ';'" is meaningless. There can only be one statement.

Answer (score 1):

I would like to add to this that I ran into some code that abused this to do nested for loops.

```cpp
for(int i=0; i<10; i++)
for(int j=0; j<10; j++)
for(int k=0; k<10; k++)
  doSomething(i, j, k);
```

In this case each for loop only has one statement (the following for loop or function) after it, and so it doesn't need braces.