# Why we have put curly-braces in for loop?

Tags: for-loop, while-loop, curly-braces, strcat, braces

When I try to make "strcat" function for practice,
I find some difference between 'for' loop with braces and without braces.
But I have questions about the reason.

At first, my code is like

```
char strcat(char *ad,char *cp)
{
    int i=0,j;

    for(i;ad[i];i++)  ///////////// here!!

    for(j=0;ad[i]=cp[j];j++){
        i++;
    }

    return ad;
}
```

In this code, 'strcat' doesn't work because of 'for' loop.
With curly-braces, it works. 
I just learn "'for' loop works with curly-braces" by rote.
But when we translate 'for' to while

```
i=0
while(str[i])
i++;
```

We didn't use curly braces, but it works.

I want to know reason about this.

Comment: Hint 1: you're missing a semicolon somewhere. Use an editor able to indent C code, and you'll realize where. Hint 2: There are more issues with your code. Turn on all warnings in your compiler, and read what the compiler tells you.

Comment: Not sure if I understand your question correctly, but is this a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26289546/what-does-a-for-loop-without-curly-braces-do ?