# Why does it not work to use multiple "if"s but it does work to use "if"s and "else if"s inside a while loop?

Tags: c, if-statement, while-loop, getchar

This was my code without using *else if*:

```
#include <stdio.h>

main()
{
    long s = 0, t = 0, n = 0;
    int c;
    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF)
        if (c == ' ')
            ++s;
        if (c == '\t')
            ++t;
        if (c == '\n')
            ++n;
    printf("spaces: %d tabulations: %d newlines: %d", s, t, n);
}
```

This is the code using *else if*:

```
#include <stdio.h>

main()
{
    long s = 0, t = 0, n = 0;
    int c;
    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF)
        if (c == ' ')
            ++s;
        else if (c == '\t')
            ++t;
        else if (c == '\n')
            ++n;
    printf("spaces: %d tabulations: %d newlines: %d", s, t, n);
}
```

For a reason, not using the *else if* doesn't work. What is the reason? I know that using *if* does it one by one while using *else if* stops at the first statement that is true. This has a difference in performance. Anyhow not using *else if* in this particular (if not other) while loop doesn't seem to work.

Thanks.

Comment: C is not Python. The indentation doesn't mean all those if's are part of the same block.

Comment: Missing `{ }` round the whole thing.

Comment: first example "works" because the first "if" statement only is wrapped by while. Second example is fully wrapped by while. I'd say the second example works. First doesn't.

Comment: You might want to read this, not sure if it's a proper duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11734604/if-block-without-curly-braces-makes-subsequent-else-if-nested

Comment: Thanks guys. This totally shows how forgetting one curved brackets is important. This means I can use "if" and "else if" without curved brackets, right?

P.S I am new to C, so sorry about so dumb post.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Correctly indented, your first program looks like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

main()
{
    long s = 0, t = 0, n = 0;
    int c;
    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF)
        if (c == ' ')
            ++s;
    if (c == '\t')
        ++t;
    if (c == '\n')
        ++n;
    printf("spaces: %d tabulations: %d newlines: %d", s, t, n);
}
```

The body of a `while` loop is a single statement.

`if ... else if ... else if ... else` all forms one big statement. By separating your conditions into several statements (`if`, `if`, `if`), you've moved all but the first one out of the while loop.

To avoid this problem, always use a compound statement (i.e. a block: `{` ... `}`) as the body of a `while` or `if` statement.

By the way, `main()` hasn't been valid C since 1999. It should be `int main(void)`.

Comment: Thanks, really appreciate it. Also I am studying C from the original book by Brian Kernighan, which in main is used without return data type, as it is from the 1980s. I used Visual Studio to compile it, and it didn't give any errors. Thanks for the correction, though.

Answer (score 1):

From [standard](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.8.5) (Only selected the relevant portions of the grammar rules)

```
   iteration-statement: while ( expression ) statement

   statement: selection-statement

   selection-statement:
             if ( expression ) statement
             if ( expression ) statement else statement
```

You are writing an iteration statement - which consists of `while(expression)` and a single statement. That statement in your case a selection statement - now check it. Unless you use `else if` or `else` it is not a single statement - rather it's multiple statement with all except one in the while statement, rest are outside of it.

Your code basically means this

```
  while ((c = getchar()) != EOF){ <--- the selection statement
    if (c == ' ')
        ++s;
  }<-- 
  if (c == '\t')
        ++t;
  if (c == '\n')
        ++n;
```

Putting brackets in the blocks and indentation will make you refrain from this kind of errors.

Answer (score 1):

Because you forgot the braces around the `while`, so it only loops through the first `if` statement, then exits the loop and evaluates the other two `if` statements.

Also, why are you not using a `switch` statement?

```
while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
    switch(c) {
       case ' ':
          ++s;
          break; 
       case  '\t':
          ++t;
          break;
       case '\n':
          ++n;
          break;
    }
}
printf("spaces: %d tabulations: %d newlines: %d", s, t, n);
```